# Unix Terminal pointer being freed was not allocated, [Process completed]

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

When I open the terminal on my Mac I getting the following message and I'm unable to get out of it. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

```
Last login: Fri Mar  6 17:49:23 on ttys000
login({some string of characters}) malloc: *** error for object {some other string of characters}: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Your `bash` looks broken - did you install anything recently that might have affected it?

Comment: I installed Bit Coin - QT today, I just uninstalled in and it didn't change.

Comment: Okay I uninstalled the software and did a restart and now it works.